# ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress using Oracle Express

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-xe

I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition.  I'm on Windows 7-64Bit

I get this error when trying to access the database:

**ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress**

I set up the express edition more than a year ago, and I've used it primarily for a single database instance that I access through SQL Developer.  I really do not do much as far as DBA administration on this, so I am not familiar with the points of failure.  But I know this will not fix itself by waiting longer.  I've tried rebooting and waiting several days.  I cannot log in using any userId I've created.

I've googled solutions and am running a console as a system administrator.  Here is what happens when I try to make repairs.

```
>sqlplus /nolog
SQL>connect / as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Others that have had the same ORA-01033 do not seem to get this error.

I really don't even need the databases.  If there is a way to wipe my data clean and start again, I'd be happy.  But it is not obvious to me how to even do that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this as the oracle user?

Comment: shutdown abort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe restarting the applicable windows service will bounce the database.

```
net stop oracleservicexe
net start oracleservicexe
```

Alternatively you can connect as `sys` and provide the password instead of using internal authentication, then bounce the database from there.

```
>sqlplus /nolog
SQL>connect sys as sysdba
Password:
```

You may also want to check the alert log for what, if anything, is keeping the database from completing startup or shutdown.